# how to split a string from scanner input in java

Tags: java, string, split

How do I split a string from a scanner input?
Here is my code. I can only get array0 (parts[0])

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the input sentence");

        String sentence = input.next();

        String[] parts = sentence.split(" ");

        System.out.println(parts[3]);

        input.close();

   }

}
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are you typing in here and what's the expected outcome for that input?

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` function will only return the next token. So, if your input has three words separated by a space, it will only return one word at a time. You need to use `nextLine()` method instead, in order to get the full input sentence.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the input sentence");

    String sentence = input.nextLine();

    String[] parts = sentence.split(" ");

    System.out.println(parts[3]);

    input.close();

   }
}
```

If you really want to use `next()` method, you would need to use a while-loop and loop until you reach the end of the sentence.